# Помогите с лабораторной работой

Tags: c++, математика

Для десяти выстрелов, координаты которых задаются с клавиатуры, вывести текстовые сообщения о попадании в мишень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мега туплю с математикой, прошу помощи, как правильно составить отрезки попадания. Мои попытки:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

bool is_hit(double x, double y, double a, double b, double r)
{
    return ((x <= a) && (x > 0) && (y <= b) && (y > 0) && (y >= std::sqrt(1 - x * x))) || ((std::fabs(x) <= r) && (x < 0) && (y >= -b) && (std::fabs(y) <= r) && (y < 0) && (y >= -std::sqrt(1 - x * x)));
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    double radius, a, b;
    std::cout << "Введите радиус окружности: ";
    std::cin >> radius;

    std::cout << "\nВведите a и b: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    double x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\n[Выстрел " << i + 1 << "]\nВведите x и y: ";
        std::cin >> x >> y;

        std::cout << "\nx = " << x << "\ny = " << y;
        is_hit(x, y, a, b, radius) ? std::cout << "\n\nПопал!\n" : std::cout << "\n\nМимо!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мишень — это черное, то для попадания в первую часть, вверху справа, что надо?

```
0 <= x <= a
0 <= y <= b
x^2 + y^2 >= R^2
```

Т.е.

```
(x >= 0 && x <= a && y >= 0 && y <= b && x*x + y*y >= R*R)
```

А в ту, что слева внизу

```
-a <= x <= 0
-b <= y <= 0
x^2 + y^2 <= R^2
```

Т.е.

```
(x <= 0 && x >= -a && y <= 0 && y >= -b && x*x + y*y <= R*R)
```

А теперь объединяем:

```
if ((x >= 0 && x <= a && y >= 0 && y <= b && x*x + y*y >= R*R) ||
    (x <= 0 && x >= -a && y <= 0 && y >= -b && x*x + y*y <= R*R)) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что a и b - координаты центра мишени?

Я бы вычислял расстояние от центра мишени до точки попадания и сравнивал бы его с радиусом

AB = sqrt(pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)); где а - координата по х, b - координата по y;

```
for(short i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cin >> x >> y;
        if (sqrt(pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2)) <= radius) cout << "\n  Попал!";
}
```

Comment: a и b - это стороны прямоугольника на рисунке, а x, y - координаты выстрела